# Making a TFS Branch Read-Only

Tags: tfs, branch

We are trying to follow the branching strategy from the [TFS Branching Guide](http://tfsbranchingguideii.codeplex.com/) and have reached the point where we have made a branch representing a release, which should now be made read-only.

In the Properties|Security tab for the branch, it presents six user groups each with 10 permissions other than Read. Do I have to go through and click Deny on 60 check boxes, or is there a better way to make this branch read-only?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Right-click the branch in the Source Control Explorer, and select the **Lock...** option

EDIT:
This seems to get missed a lot when people are finding this so I'll make it more obvious.

**Locks appear as a "pending change" for the person who locked the item. As long as the lock is in effect, it will appear as a pending change. When a commit is made of that pending change, the lock is released**. While the lock is in effect, the locked branch is effectively read-only, since (to simplify) the locker is the only user who can make commits. The act of committing is what releases any locks on the branch.

h/t @AakashM for pointing that out in the comments

Comment: This leaves the lock hanging around as a pending change. Removing check-in permissions is the right answer.

Comment: +1 The lock simply doesn't work... As a locker, I have the "add lock" change pending, and on top of that, I can go and check-in files freely.
Changing permissions works better IMHO.

Comment: Added the lock, tried to commit and the server responded with " All of the changes were either unmodified files or locks. The changes have been undone by the server."

Comment: as @AakashM says in the comments to his answer, "...clicking Check In with the lock item checked is what releases the lock. It's... somewhat unintuitive."

Comment: Nice ... amazing user interaction. I've been trying to fix the 'unlocked' branch when I checked it in for 2 hours ... argh :\ Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: The only problem is now I keep getting asked to check in.

Answer (score 11):

As a quick-n-dirty, you could Lock it for Check Out (although the locker would have to remember to keep the lock in their pending changes forever... which makes me think there's a better way)

Comment: the locker wouldn't have to remember to keep the lock - it would just prevent check-ins. The best strategy in that case is for Devs with pending changes to shelve them on the server.

Comment: What I mean is that the Lock sits in the lockers pending changes window as if it were an actual 'pending change' - and clicking Check In with the lock item checked is what releases the lock. It's... somewhat unintuitive.

Comment: I have a "management" workspace where I perform merges, hold locks, etc.  That way I don't see them during day to day development.

Comment: @JoshE,  What about having a dedicated account for locking things -->LockUserAccount, only this account can Lock and Unlock things?

Comment: @Legends nothing stopping you from doing that, but I'm not sure what value you'd get... you'd still need to deal with the pending changes of locks/check-in for unlocks, it'd just be a step removed from before

Answer (score 9):

To answer the 2nd part of the question -- removing or denying the Read permission effectively denies everything else.

Answer (score 5):

As is mentioned above locking is not a very nice strategy. The correct way of handling this is setting permissions.

You can effectively make files readonly. Users trying to modify the files will get a message 'checkout denied'

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252587.aspx#project_level

In VS2013: Team Explorer -> Settings -> Security/Version Control

Answer (score 3):

Deny Check In for domain\domain users

Answer (score 2):

If you have inheritance set to 'On', the best way I've found is to:

1. 'Deny' all permissions except 'Read' to the 'Reader' group, and
2. Add all other groups (except Project Administrators) to the 'Reader' group.

Then, all groups within the Reader group will inherit the 'Deny' permissions and not be able to do anything but read.