# How to make a TFS Branch Read Only

Tags: tfs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Making a TFS Branch Read-Only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038595/making-a-tfs-branch-read-only)

I want to make a branch read-only in TFS 2010 as the branch has been released and will not have any further changes.

Currently I see two options, neither of which I like:

1) Change security on each branch so people don't have write permissions. This is going to bey really tedious.

2) Exclusive check out the entire branch. This however will leave hundreds of files in the pending changes window per branch.

Is there a different way to read-only a branch that doesn't have the negatives of the above two options? I have only looked though the UI, not any command line options yet.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: (in particular note [Richard Berg's comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038595/making-a-tfs-branch-read-only#comment855629_1038628) )

Comment: @AakashM is correct, the suggestion to use Lock here is not the best advice and this should be handled with permissions.  (Why is it tedious?  The number of users?  Just deny access for an entire group.)  If something were to happen to your workspace where you held the lock, it would effectively open the branch back up.

Comment: Alternatively try cloaking the branch - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms181378(v=VS.80).aspx